# Code organisation and differentiation between tools and utils packages

Tags: java, code-organization

About code organisation in packages, i have seen both `tools` and `util` used for the same purpose, ie. to contain classes that help with trivial and frequent tasks.

Example:

```
+ foo.util
|--  StringManipulation.java
|--  MyLogger.java
+ foo.tools
|--  InputSanitization.java
|--  IdentifyOS.java
|--  Whatever.java
```

From your experience, is there anything that distinguishes `tools` from `utils`?
How should such reusable code be organised?

What is the generaly accepted responsibility (historically or semantically) of both and when should I use one over the other when organizing my code.

Conversely, where should I expect to find the more specialized or on the contrary more low level code in those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both "tools" and "utils" are bad names for classes/packages.  It is not object oriented.  It is a way of saying, "I don't know what to name this thing so I'll just give it a generic name".

What you should do is figure out what these tools/utils are *really* doing and name them appropriately.

Comment: I strongly disagree, tools and utils are perfectly valid *package* names for.... tools and utils package. The question was "when should I use one or the other". Besides, not all programming is object oriented and so are *packages* sometimes

Answer (score 1):

Classes within the same package usually share the same or similar functionalities, or they together achieve a set of similar functionalities.  In addition, classes within the same package can access all *package-private* variables (i.e., those variables defined without `public`, `protected`, and `private`) within their package.

As for naming, while Oracle has defined [a convention for java naming packages](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html), it is developer's responsibility to have a clear naming for each package.  In your case, it is better to have some descriptions to describe the utilities and tools.  Here are some examples:

```
foo.connection.tools
foo.string.utils
```

In this way, users can know the tools is for connections, utils is for string manipulations.